# Convert quotes to Space

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace this double quotes in string:
Need to convert this string to valid JSON

```
data = '[{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Length","Keywords":"6.49"","AttributeComments":"Value Found","OtherComment":""},{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Width","Keywords":"2.75"","AttributeComments":"Value Found","OtherComment":""},{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Height","Keywords":"8.46"","AttributeComments":"Value Found","OtherComment":""},{"Attribute":"Diameter","Keywords":"","AttributeComments":"No Value Found","OtherComment":""}]'
```

Expected output:

```
data = '[{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Length","Keywords":"6.49","AttributeComments":"Value Found","OtherComment":""},{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Width","Keywords":"2.75","AttributeComments":"Value Found","OtherComment":""},{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Height","Keywords":"8.46","AttributeComments":"Value Found","OtherComment":""},{"Attribute":"Diameter","Keywords":"","AttributeComments":"No Value Found","OtherComment":""}]'
```

I had tried using python replace function:-

`data = data.replace('""', '"')`

But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace "" with "

```
import re
data = '[{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Length","Keywords":"6.49"",...}]'
data = re.sub(':""', ":''", data)
data = data.replace('""','"')
data = data.replace("''",'""')
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Length","Keywords":"6.49","AttributeComments":"Value Found","OtherComment":""},{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Width","Keywords":"2.75","AttributeComments":"Value Found","OtherComment":""},{"Attribute":"Assembled Product Height","Keywords":"8.46","AttributeComments":"Value Found","OtherComment":""},{"Attribute":"Diameter","Keywords":"","AttributeComments":"No Value Found","OtherComment":""}]
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply but I need valid JSON output.

Comment: I have edited the question your output was correct for small string.

Comment: Updated answer @ShubhamShinde

Comment: Great, please accept my answer. Happy coding!!! @ShubhamShinde

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
data.replace('"",'"')
```

It replaces double quotes with a single one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this problem is not been solved by this approach

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods you can use:

1. Python has a built-in function `str.replace(old, new)`

   So, you can directly replace it use: `data.replace('""','"')`

---

2. Regex (Regular Expression)

   `import re
    data = re.sub('""+', '"', data)`

   That code means if quotes continuous appears twice, it will auto convert them to a single quote.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this problem is not been solved by this approach.

Comment: Regex solution is replacing all double quotes to single quotes. Due to which the values which are empty and having double quotes is also been getting converted to single quotes producing invalid JSON.